# Doubts relationship between 3 tables Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have these 3 table, and I want to do is group events by user. Now, the query, it returns an event for each register of the user_events table.

**users**
(id, name, email, password)

**events**
(id, name, date, finish)

**user_events**
(user_id, event_id)

The route is:

```
https://api.domain.com/users/{user}/events
```

And this the query:

```
function index(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isJson()) {
        $userId = $request->user('api')->id;
        $events = UserEvents::where('user_id', $userId)
            ->whereHas('events', function($query) {
                $query->where('finish', 0);
            }   )
            ->with(['events' => function($query) {
                $query->where('finish', 0)
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc');
            }])
            ->get();
        Log::info($request->user('api')->id);
        // Fin nuevo

        return response()->json(['events'=>$events], 200);
    }

    return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401, []);
```

And the result for this query:

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "user_id": 1,
            "event_id": 1,
            "events": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Test 1",
                    "date": "09/06/2018",
                    "finish": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "user_id": 1,
            "event_id": 34,
            "events": [
                {
                    "id": 34,
                    "name": "Test 34",
                    "date": "09/06/2019",
                    "finish": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I make to get the user events grouped like this?

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "user_id": 1
            "events": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Test 1",
                    "date": "09/06/2018",
                    "finish": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 34,
                    "name": "Test 34",
                    "date": "09/06/2019",
                    "finish": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Generally, you don't query directly against a `pivot` table, so your `UserEvents` Model is pointless. You'd do a query `User::whereHas('events', ...)->with('events', ...)`, or `Event::whereHas('users', ...)->with('users', ...)`. That way, you'd get a list of `User` records with a nested `Events` relationship, or a list of `Event` records, with a nested `Users` relationship.

Comment: Thanks you Tim, you help me with your answer to to solve the problem.